# Declare an object of a class inside a condition

Tags: ios, objective-c

My requirement is that I want to declare an object of a class depending upon a condition that deviceFamily is iPad or iPhone. 
I have developed an application for iPhone. Now I want to develop same application for iPad. Now I want to have two different `.h` , `.m` and `.xib` for iPhone and iPad with different names. But I want to use the same name object of two different classes in `AppDelegate` class of universal application.

Something like in `.h` file:

```
if(IS_iPad)
{
 ViewController_iPad * obj;
}
else
{
 ViewController_iPhone * obj;
}
```

So the I can use the same name of the object throughout the application.

How can I achieve this. Help!

Comment: So want two different versions of the same app; one for iPhone and one for iPad?

Comment: I don't understand your problem: When you define you "obj" as in the code above, the scope is local to the 2 alternatives. So you can give them the same name or not; it does not matter. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

This is probably the  not best approach for creating a 'Universal' app (both iPad and iPhone) but for all of the instances I've seen adopting this model they seem to take the logic you have down a chain in regards to controllers...

UIViewController *sharedController = [[UIViewController alloc]init]; // things that are shared between both devices go in here (write once no duplication)

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) // PAD
{
    ViewController_iPad * obj;
}
else if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) // PHONE
{
    ViewController_iPhone * obj;
}
```

Both of the view controller above should either include sharedController as a property to make use of the code in there OR better...

Make sharedController the 'base class'. Then make both ViewController_iPad and ViewController_iPhone sub classes of this class (shared).

To do this, in both ViewController_iPhone and ViewController_iPad's .h header files, set them as subclasses of sharedController like this.

@interface ViewController_iPad : sharedController

Its one approach if you really have to do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

I would look into **class clusters** as explained at the [iOS7 Tech Talks](https://developer.apple.com/tech-talks/videos/). Look at the end of the session "Architecting Modern Apps, Part 2", in the slides it starts at page 120.

Essentially, you can hide the exact implementation of a class from other classes that use it. In the image below, the app uses a class "Download Controller" but does not need to know if the OS is capable of `NSURLSession` or needs to default to `NSURLConnection`. I think this kind of pattern would work well with your problem.

[image]

The code for two such implementations would look something like this:

```
@interface MyViewController_iPhone : MyViewController @end 
@interface MyViewController_iPad   : MyViewController @end 

@implementation MyViewController

+ (instancetype)newViewController {
   if (IS_iPad) {
     return [[MyViewController_iPad alloc] init];
   } else {
     return [[MyViewController_iPhone alloc] init];
   } 
}
... 
@end
```

Comment: My interface for two classes is inherited from UIView. 1) CustomView1 and 2) CustomView2. By following your approach I am getting errors in accessing custom properties declared and defiened in two custom classes using . operator. Only able to access properties of UIView. @mundi

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I understand now what you want to achieve: You want to define alternatively different objects, but access them outside the declaration scope by the same name. If so, what about:

```
@property (strong) UIViewController *obj;
... 
if(IS_iPad)
{
 obj = [[ViewController_iPad alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
}
else
{
 obj = [[ViewController_iPhone alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
}
```

I assume both classes are subclasses of `UIViewController`, so the assignment would be OK. Of course one had to use the proper initialization for the view controllers.

Comment: I believe the OP is looking for a compile-time solution.

Comment: The object is of UIView type. If I use it UIView type at the declaration time, then custom properties are not inherited.

Comment: hmmm... In your example you used as classes for "obj" ViewController_iPad and ViewController_iPhone, which are not UIViews. Anyway, if you assign such objects to their superclass, they will keep their subclass properties. You just had to cast the superclass to the actual subclass to access them.